# Encryption, possible base64?

Tags: c#, encryption, base64, sha1

Given the string

```
KlVkeNK76V27D2MSBOhfNC6eNtA=
```

This look like base64 encoded. However, I tried using convert to base64 with C# , result is a garbage string.

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
   var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
   return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

If I use this:

```
https://hashkiller.co.uk/sha1-decrypter.aspx
```

then it give a nicely SHA1 hash:

```
2a556478d2bbe95dbb0f631204e85f342e9e36d0
```

Can anyone show me how to decrypt it with C#?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What should it be decrypted to? What do you expect to get? Where is it from?

Comment: There is a difference between encoding and decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They simply print the hex value of the base64-decoded string:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("KlVkeNK76V27D2MSBOhfNC6eNtA=");
string hexString = new SoapHexBinary(bytes).ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
```

(where `SoapHexBinary` is a .NET class that converts `byte[]` to hex `string`)